# Magento - How can I change the sidebar order?

Tags: xml, magento, layout

I installed the Modern Theme on Magento 1.7.0.1 and the extension "Sidebar Navigation Menu Professional" from CODNITIVE, so I have three boxes ("Shop By", "Categories", "Compare Products" and "My Cart") at the left sidebar. Now I want to change the order in this way:

1. My Cart
2. Categories
3. Compare Products.

I tried to change the order via editing the catalog.xml with the lines

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

and changed it in this way:

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

so that "My Cart" is over the Compare box - and that´s all what I know cause it's hard to find a clear solution for that it the forum on magentocommerce.com. And I don't know the .xml-file for the Categories-box.

Another advice from CODNITIVE was to creat an own locale.xml file from where you can edit the complete page layout. But that doesn't really help me, because I am not a programmer.

Could anybody help my to edit the Sidebar layout? (Excuse my English.)

Answer (score -1):

For Categories U can check the **sidenav.xml**  and change the navigation block position there.

Check [this Post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/269953/#t393311) for details.